# postgres alternative to bulk collect limit from oracle pl/sql

Tags: postgresql, plsql, plpgsql

I've a procedure in Oracle PL/SQL which fetches transactional data based on certain condition, then performs some logical calculations. I used cursor to store the SQL and then I used FETCH (cursor) BULK COLLECT INTO (table type variable) LIMIT 10000, iterated over this table variable to perform calculation and ultimately storing the value in a DB table. Once 10000 rows have been processed, query will be executed to fetch next set of records,

This helped me limiting number of times SQL is executed via cursor and limiting the number of records loaded into memory.

I am trying to migrate this code to plpgsql. How can I achieve this functionality in plpgsql?

Comment: You could fetch into an array with a limit clause, but I doubt it would actually improve performance

Answer (score 0):

You cannot achieve this functionality in PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an extension https://github.com/okbob/dbms_sql . It can be used for reduce of necessary work related to migration from Oracle to Postgres.

But you don't need this feature in Postgres. Although PL/pgSQL is similar to PL/SQL, the architecture is very different - and bulk collect operations are not necessary.